# Transformar un JSON a otro JSON

Tags: java, json

Estoy buscando algún tipo de librería o herramienta para java que sirva para dado un JSON, este lo transforme en otro JSON con ciertos cambios. El objetivo es evitar un
JSON -> XML-> XLST -> XML -JSON

Las estructuras principalmente se mantendrán intactas habrán claves que tengan el nombre cambiado, y otros que directamente serán eliminados ya que es información que no se quiere.

Voy a poner un  ejemplo inventado

**JSON a transformar**

```
{
    "idCompany":1,
    "companyName":"test",
    "idTipe":4,
    "observations":"this is som observations",
    "bigCompany": false,
    "headerText":"This is a header",
    "Employees":{
        [
          "idEmployee":1,
          "name":"Phil",
          "Surname":"Thomson",
          "idPosition":1,
          "obsevations": "this is an observations",
          "incidences": "health Problem"
        ],
          ...
    }
}
```

**JSON a obtener**

```
{
    "idCompany":1,
    "companyName":"test",
    "idTipe":4,
    "observations":"this is som observations",
    "isBigCompany": false,
    "Employees":{
        [
          "idEmployee":1,
          "name":"Phil",
          "Surname":"Thomson",
          "jobLevel":1,
          "obsevations": "this is an observations"
        ],
          ...
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo hay un par de campos que se han eliminado y otros que solo se han cambiado los nombres

¿alguien conoce alguna herramienta o librería para JAVA que pueda hacer esto?

Gracias

Comment: Pero ese cambio lo puedes realizar perfectamente con Javascript e incluso con Java.. no necesitas una librería especial

Comment: El javascript no esta contemplado. Y preferiria tener que evitar hacer una conversion a String para aplicar los cambios y luego reconvertir a Json. Y para evitar tener que reinventar la rueda, por eso preguntaba si alguien conoce algo que pueda hacer eso.

Comment: Nadie dice que debes hacer una conversión a String para aquello. Lo que deberías hacer es crear una estructura basada en el JSON que deseas y enviar por parametro la estructura que deseas trabajar..

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Al final ha sido similar a lo que tu has dicho. Tengo que recorrer todo el JSON recibido y  con un fichero recibido con los cambios a realizar, ir aplicandolos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de un [par](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model) [de](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603033/removing-json-elements-with-jackson) [investigaciones](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.json.JSONObject&method=remove), 2 librerías populares pueden realizar eso: [JSON](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) y [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). El código resulta similar para ambos pero con orígenes de librería diferentes (como nota, eso no significa que funcionen igual, solamente que se parecen en varios aspectos incluyendo este).

El código en cuestión:

```
//Jackson
JsonNode jsonEntrante= mapper.readTree("{\"idCompany\": 1,\"companyName\": \"test\"}");
ObjectNode json = (ObjectNode) jsonEntrante;
json.remove("companyName");

//JSON
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"idCompany\": 1,\"companyName\": \"test\"}");
json.remove("companyName");
```

Comment: la opcion de jackson fue la mas cercana y me ayudo mucho el [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234451/transformar-un-json-a-otro-json/234645#234645) para llegar una solucion. Vi que no era posible hacer una sustitucion de clave y que tenia que hacer un eliminar y crear uno nuevo. Igualmente, estuve teniendo el problema de que jackson me ha estado escapando los '\' y me toco reinventar la rueda con GSON.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque tal vez no sea exactamente lo que quieres, una posibilidad sería con la librería jackson.

Deberías hacer algo parecido a esto:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Contenedora {
    private String idCompany;
    private String companyName;
    private Integer idTipe;
    private String observations;
    private Boolean bigCompany;
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @JsonSetter("isBigCompany")
    public void setBigCompany(Boolean bigCompany) {
        this.bigCompany = bigCompany;
    }
    // Resto Getters y setters

}
```

Esto es para que te hagas una idea, deberías de hacer algo similar en la clase Employee.

Explico un poco lo que hace todo esto, la anotación `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` arriba de la clase, lo que hace es lo que dice, ignora las propiedades que le lleguen sin dar error.
Cuando deserialices Jackson mapeará de forma automática las propiedades que tengan el mismo nombre del json al objeto.
Cuando serialices hará lo mismo con la excepción de la propiedad bigCompany que la renombrará a isBigCompany.

Como informacón adicional debes saber que también existe la anotación `@JsonGetter`
y que `@JsonSetter` también se puede utilizar para tratar lo nulos como `""`

Cuando recibas el String que contiene el json deberás proceder de forma similar a esta:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Contenedora cont = om.readValue(jsonData, Contenedora.class);
```

Esto te convierte el String al objeto Contenedora, si después haces:

```
String jsonConvertido = om.writeValueAsString(cont);
```

En jsonConvertido deberías tener el resultado que tú esperas.

En esta página tienes un ejemplo https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/renaming-properties.html

Y en el siguiente enlace esta la librería de jackson. Si utilizas maven pues añades la dependencia en el pom y si no te la descargas y la añades en el classpath

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core

Comment: Tu respuesta ees muy buena. La putada es que no se adaptaba exactamente a lo que necesitaba por que (esto no lo puse) el JSON que recibimos puede cambiar la cantidad de valores que recibimos  y para conseguir un codigo fácilmente mantenible, un objeto del tipo que vamos a devolver se volvía complicado y dificil de mantener. Dificil de mantener por el hecho de que tiene que funcionar tambien a la inversa. Los json que manda el cliente, se les tiene que cambiar el nombre de las claves para como espera recibirlo el servidor. Debido a esto, no deseaba tener un objeto. Igualmente gracias.